# Unable to search for '\\n' using regular expressions in python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
>>> import re
>>> a='''\\n5
... 8'''
>>> b=re.findall('\\n[0-9]',a)
>>> print(b)
['\n8']
```

Why does it show `\n8` and not `\n5`?
I used a `\` in front of `\n` the first time.
I am finding the use of raw `string` in regex in python a bit confusing. To me it does not seem to be making any changes to the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in strings, the newline character is considered that, a single character.

When you do `\\n5` you're escaping the `\`, so that's literally printing `\n5`, and not a newline by Python standards.

When you search for a regex such as `\\n[0-9]` though, in the first `\` you're escaping the `\n` *regex* expression, so in the end you're looking for `\n` which is Python's newline. That matches the actual newline in your string, but not `\\n` which is two separate characters, an escaped `\` and an `n`.

Comment: How do i get \\n5 in the result?

Comment: @VaibhavPandey if you want to get both `\\n5` and `\n8`, you can use a non-capture group to check for one of the two: `'(?:\\n|\\\\n)[0-9]'`. If you just want the `\\n5`, include double escaped slashes: `'\\\\n[0-9]'`.

Answer (score 2):

`\\n` is not a newline, it's an escaped backslash with an n.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '''\n5
... 8'''
>>> a=re.findall('\\n[0-9]',a)
>>> print(a)
['\n5', '\n8']
```

Answer (score 1):

because `\\n5` is not valid new line, it will print `\n5`